# Как скачать плагин Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Собственно, вопрос обозначен. Пример плагина: http://rherrmann.github.io/gonsole/

Там обозначен сервер обновлений, с которого нужно устанавливать через Help->Install new software, есть кнопка для перетаскивания... А ссылки для скачивания нет. Онлайн установка невозможна.

p.s. Какие же злодеи придумали онлайн-установочники!

Comment: Если нет возможности установить через online, скачай исходники и собери.

Answer (score 1):

1. Перейти по ссылке
2. Далее **Installation** -> кнопка install -> [ссылка](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=1789454)
3. **Where can I get the Eclipse Marketplace Client** -> MPC is included in all of the packages available from the **Eclipse download page** -> [ссылка 2](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)
4. Выбрать нужный плагин и скачать